# Show that the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt y,y=0$ has non-unique solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Show that the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt y,y(0)=0$ has non-unique solution.

To solve this problem I used Lipschitz theorem. My solution goes like this:

> Let $f$ be continuous in an unbounded domain $$D:a\leq x\leq b,-\infty\leq y\leq \infty.$$ Let $f$ satisfy a Lipschitz condition in $D$.  That is, assume $\exists k\in\Bbb R$such that $|f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)|\leq k|y_1-y_2|$ for all $(x,y_1),(x,y_2)\in D.$Then the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)$ and $y(x_0)=y_0$ ( where $(x_0,y_0)\in D$ ) has a unique solution in $[a,b].$( Lipschitz Theorem) Now, here, we have $f(x,y)=\sqrt y$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac {1}{2\sqrt y}.$ We see that $f$ is continuous everywhere, but $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac {1}{2\sqrt y},$ is not continuous at $y=0$ and also not bounded at $y=0$ and so, Lipschitz condition is not satisfied( since $f$ is said to satisfy a Lipschitz condition with respect to $y$ in a domain $D$ iff $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is bounded). Thus, we can conclude that  the given differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt y$ and $y(0)=0$ has no unique solution.

But I am confused as I studied Picard's Theorem as well which goes like this:

> The differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)$ and $y(x_0)=y_0$ has a unique solution on $|x-x_0|\leq h$ , if both $f$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ are continuous in the domain $D=\{(x,y):|x-x_0|\leq h,|y-y_0|\leq k,h,k>0\}$

If we use this theorem to conclude the above assertion in the question is true, then the reasoning would go like this:

> Here, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$  is not continuous in the domain $D$ if $(0,y)\in D.$  Thus, Picard's theorem won't be satisfied if $(0,y) \in D.$ But according to Picard's theorem, we have: the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt y$ and $y(0)=0$ has a unique solution on $|x|\leq h(,h>0)$, if both $f$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ are continuous in the domain $D=\{(x,y):|x|\leq h,|y|\leq k,h,k>0\}.$ But, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is not continuous in $D$ as $(0,y)\in D.$ So, the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt y,y(0)=0$ has non-unique solution.

But I am confused whether both of my solutions (one using Lipschitz theorem and the other one using Picard's theorem) is valid or not?

*I think, Lipschitz theorem is more appropriate to solve these sort of problems as Picard's theorem, gurantees a unique solution in a particular or (better say,) a bounded domain but the Lipschitz theorem gurantees the existence of a unique solution, in an unbounded domain(**Is it**?)* **But, in this case what I did was that:**

> I showed both the Lipschitz theorem and the Picard's theorem are not satisfied for the set of equations : $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt y,y(0)=0.$

So, in general, if conditions of  Lipschitz's theorem  are not satisfied, then can we directly conclude that a set of equations, say: $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)$ and $y(x_0)=y_0$ (where $(x_0,y_0)$ is in the domain of $f$ ) do not have a unique solution in the domain of $f,$ *just as the thing was with this case?* **Then, the usage of Picard's theorem further is unnecessary(here), isn't it?**

Comment: I thought the Picardy theorem and Lipschitz theorem are used to prove the uniqueness of solutions? I'm not aware that you can use them the other way round to prove that solutions are not unique.

Comment: Why don't you simply solve the differential equation using "high school calculus" techniques? You'll see that your equation has a family of solutions.

Comment: Indeed, the similar equation $y'=1+\sqrt{|y|}$ is similarly likewise singular at $y=0$ but has unique solutions.

Comment: @KennyWong Neither I was aware of that as well. But our professor gave this problem while teaching about these theorems. When I asked him, "How to show that they are non-unique?" . He simply said, "Why don't you use Picard's theorem to conclude the assertion in the problem is true?". Now, to be very precise, this is my situation...

Comment: Simple calculus shows $y=\frac{x^2}{4}+C$ - Why all the complexity?

Comment: @NoChance : That is the right idea, but wrong result. Generally you get the zero solution and solutions of the form $y(x)=\frac14\max(0,x-c)^2$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, Aha...Thanks for your kind correction. I overlooked the constants as $y(0)=0$. The max part is interesting.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use Lipshitz theorem that way - you are making an elementary logic mistake. $A\implies B$ does **not** imply $\lnot A\implies \lnot B$. In your case $A$: "function satisfies Lipshitz condition", $B$: "differential equation has a unique solution". (To see why, replace $A$ with "$x$ is a fish" and $B$ with "$x$ lives in the water", and consider whales!)

Also, you can notice that the function $y=0$ satisfies the solution, as well as $y=\left(\frac{x-C}{2}\right)^2$ for any $C\in\mathbb R$ and $x\ge C$. This doesn't just mean $C=0$: you can pack up many more functions the following way: choose a constant $C\ge 0$ and say:

$$y=\begin{cases}0&x<C\\\left(\frac{x-C}{2}\right)^2&x\ge C\end{cases}$$

(It is a part of the $x$ axis all the way on the left from $(0,0)$, and on the right all the way up to $(C,0)$, after which point it rises up as a parabola.)

Comment: Your solution is partially wrong, the slope is always positive, there is no falling branch. It would be correct if the task were to solve $y'^2=y$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann True, thanks. Fixed.